# Open Binary image "edf" format with Mathematica

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica

I want to opena binary images with the extension "edf" with Mathematica. Do you know how is it possible ? Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

EDF is a supported import format.

See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ImportFormats.html

So use `image = Import["yourfilename.edf"]`

Comment: Thank you ! In fact this is not the edf format already supported. This is another kind of file. To open it with gnulplot I have to write "plot "data.edf" binary filetype=edf with image". I am looking to find the equivalent method with Mathematica .. without any success.